# How to write integration tests for REST API in Go?

Tags: rest, unit-testing, http, go, integration-testing

I have a simple web application like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "io"
)

// hello world, the web server
func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}

func HelloServer2(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world2!\n")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)
    http.HandleFunc("/hello2", HelloServer2)
    http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil)
}
```

I want to write a test, which starts my application, then makes call to specific port, then gets **hello, world!** or **hello, world2!** and asserts it. I cannot understand, how to do it with help [httptest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/).

I cannot test my endpoints like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42474385/4167563 because I don't use http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/.

Comment: this is a good video about that matter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVFEV-ieeew

Comment: @Fabricio thank you.

Comment: @Max The accepted answer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42474385/4167563 is not specific to Gorilla mux.  Create the server using `ts := httptest.NewServer(http.DefaultServeMux)` to test your application.

Comment: @CeriseLimón oh, thank you.